# How do you get express to send back some data without directing to a new page

Tags: html, mongodb, express, ejs

I have this searching app that Im developing using express and mongo where a user searches for something, and then gets back results from a mongo db.

The results are displayed on the left hand side of the page as shown in this image
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMDBQ.png)

I have details about each entry stored in a separate mongo collection, and I want it such that a user can click on an entry which will send a request back to the server asking for the details using an id, then the server will send back the data from the mongo collection to the user. Then the data is displayed to the user on the right side.

How do I do this so that It doesn't redirect/direct to a different page once the data is sent back from the server and I lose all the searches on the left. I want to keep the left searches so that a user can click on a different search result without having to go back to the previous page.

Basically, is there any way to send express data back to the original page, then displaying that data in a separate div without having the page redirect or change anything apart from displaying the new data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, change the HTML code inside a div wrapper.

##### Example:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper"></div>
    <!-- Search elements -->
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
<script>
    // Change the page
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: but how would you do that?

Comment: @oneloop [`document.querySelector(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)